# Cannot put swing components onto frame in run()?

Tags: java, swing

```
public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");

        frame.add(button);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This code will not display the button, only the frame. Additionally, I tested the exact code outside of a run method and it worked fine. Can I not display buttons or other components in the run method? If so, why not? Perhaps my understand of the EventQueue is off.

Comment: You haven't got a `run` method, just a `Runnable` class with some statements scattered in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure `BorderLayout` likes it when components already exist on a container...

Since `BorderLayout` is the default layout manager for a `JFrame`, simply remove the `setLayout` call...

```
frame.add(button);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

In the future though, set the layout manager first ;)